# Jenkins warning that a secret was wrongly used with string interpolation when in fact I was just using a string that happens to be equal do the secret

Tags: jenkins

I have a credential named 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD' that has a value o 'test'.

I also have a job that is `junit '/home/jap/.local/share/docker/volumes/jenkins_home/_data/workspace/vlep-pipeline_main/test-result/*.xml'` and this job returns:

```
Warning: A secret was passed to "withEnv" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [POSTGRES_PASSWORD]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
```

```
 Archive JUnit-formatted test results -- /home/jap/.local/share/docker/volumes/jenkins_home/_data/workspace/vlep-pipeline_main/${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}-result/*.xml (self time 9ms)
```

I tried using double quotes instead, but I still get the error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with what you are doing. Jenkins makes an assumption that any secret would have enough entropy not to be mistaken for an unrelated character sequence. In your case this assumption doesn’t hold. You have two options:

1. Change the password to something more random
2. Blindside Jenkins by calling `junit` with a String parameter instead of GString.